# Return one-to-one model information with model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have 2 pretty basic Django models: User and UserProfile. I am using the REST framework and would like to include profile information when retrieving all users. I have searched the internet but was not able to find the answer. This is what I am currently trying: `User.objects.all().prefetch_related('userprofile')`

What I am trying to return is something like:

```
[
  {'email': 'email@example.com',
   'first_name': 'Test', 
   'last_name': 'McTester'},
  {'email': 'user2@example.com',
   'first_name': 'Mary',
   'last_name': 'McPherson'}
]
```

where first and last name are profile attributes. I have been able to do something similar using Flask and GraphQL but was wondering if this is possible with REST in Django.

Comment: Try using select_related('user_profile')

Comment: How did you define your models? Can you show? @user1314147

Comment: can you show models and serializers ? i may help you !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) does is load the data from `UserProfile` model beforehand based on relationship between `User` model and `UserProfile` model, so when you call `user.userprofile` it does not hit database again. But it does not return the value when you call `user`. So in your [model serializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer), you can add these two fields with [`source`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) pointing to `UserProfile`'s `first_name` and `last_name`. For example:

```
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
     first_name = serializer.CharField(source='userprofile.first_name', read_only=True)
     last_name = serializer.CharField(source='userprofile.last_name', read_only=True)

     class Meta:
         model = User
         fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

Comment: You should also use `select_related('user_profile')` instead of `prefetch_related` as singular relationships can be fetched using an `INNER JOIN` instead of incurring two queries like `prefetch_related` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You could define two serializers:

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

```py
class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    user_profile = UserProfileSerializer(many=False)

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        user_profile_data = data.pop('user_profile')
        for key, val in user_profile_data.items():
            data.update({key: val})
        return data

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']
```

Hope it helps you :)